# Why overloaded '&' operator does not triggering when the first operand is false?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators, operator-keyword

I need a little strange class which helps me to make complex predicates and stores the components which will helps me in another scenario.

My problem is that when I overloading the "&" operator (and of course the true and false operators) then my "&" operator doesn't triggers in some cases.

```
public class ObservablePredicate // : IObservable<bool> does not need now
{
    public ObservablePredicate Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<ObservablePredicate> Components { get; set; }

    public static bool operator true(ObservablePredicate x)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator false(ObservablePredicate x)
    {
        return !x.Value;
    }

    public static ObservablePredicate operator &(ObservablePredicate a, ObservablePredicate b)
    {
        if (a == null) a = new ObservablePredicate(false);
        if (b == null) b = new ObservablePredicate(false);

        var result = a.Value && b.Value;
        return new ObservablePredicate(result, a, b);
    }

    private bool _value;
    public bool Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            // do something with components if exists...
            // do something with parent if exists...
        }
    }

    public ObservablePredicate(ObservablePredicate p)
    {
        Initialise(p.Value, null);
    }

    public ObservablePredicate(bool value, params ObservablePredicate[] predicates)
    {
        predicates.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Parent = this);
        Initialise(value, predicates.ToList());
    }

    private void Initialise(bool value, List<ObservablePredicate> components)
    {
        Components = components ?? new List<ObservablePredicate>();
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

The "&" operator fires in the following situations:

```
var prediacteA = new ObservablePredicate(true);
var predicateB = new ObservablePredicate(true);
var predicateC = prediacteA && predicateB;
```

```
var prediacteA = new ObservablePredicate(true);
var predicateB = new ObservablePredicate(false);
var predicateC = prediacteA && predicateB;
```

But not in the following situations, and therefore my Components property will be empty:

```
var prediacteA = new ObservablePredicate(false);
var predicateB = new ObservablePredicate(true);
var predicateC = prediacteA && predicateB;
```

```
var prediacteA = new ObservablePredicate(false);
var predicateB = new ObservablePredicate(false);
var predicateC = prediacteA && predicateB;
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operator-overloading), `&&` operaters cannot be overloaded.

`&` is a logical AND where `&&` is a conditional logical operators also called short-circuit, which means that if the first condition is false, it will not evaluate the second condition.

Typical you would always use `&&` in if statements and other predicates and `&` when working on a bit-wise level:

`if(a && b) // where a and b is booleans`

`0b0101 & 0b0100 = 0b0100`

Comment: `&&` will invoke user-defined operators, but it will reuse the `&` operator, and it will not evaluate the second operand if the first evaluates to `false`, in line with how `&&` is supposed to work. Note that `&` is also a logical operator, but you're allowed to declare a user-defined operator for it.